# NetworkStream in C# Socket programming

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I am developing a IOS app in xamrain to communicate with hardware in which application  sending the string message to the Hardware and  hardware respond the message client reading that message through network-stream. After reading the message from the network-stream client flush the network-stream but old message still remain in network-stream. Plz suggest me the solution if anyone known.

```
private async Task CommandSendAsync() 
{
    if (sock.Connected) 
    { 
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(sock.GetStream()); 
        writer.WriteLine("abc"); 
        writer.Flush(); 
        await DataReceivedAsync();
    } 
    else { sock.Connect(192.168.1.1, 8025); } 
} 


string String = "";
public byte[] ReadJunctionSetting = new byte[1071];
int a = 0;
protected Socket SimNetSocket;
public async Task DataReceivedAsync()
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        String = "";
        var abc = sock.GetStream();
        //byte[] bytes = new byte[sock.ReceiveBufferSize];
        while ((i = abc.Read(ReadJunctionSetting, 0, ReadJunctionSetting.Length)) != 0)
        {
            abc.Flush();
            for (int j = 0; j < 1071; j++)
            {
                string c = char.ConvertFromUtf32(ReadJunctionSetting[j]);
                String += c;
            }
            abc.Read(ReadJunctionSetting, 0, ReadJunctionSetting.Length);
            break;
        }
    }
    catch
    {               

    }
}
```

Comment: Flushing the network stream should not affect the incoming data - it's hard to help you without seeing any code.

Comment: I post the code please see it....CommandsendAsync method write command to hardware ....hardware response me in datareceivedAsync function. when i read the stream second time old data still remain in the network stream.

Comment: May not relate to your current issue but you're ignoring `i` after testing it for non-zero. You shouldn't. It tells you *how many bytes* of `ReadJunctionSetting` have *actually* been populated. You're not guaranteed that it's the same as the length of that buffer (it could be as little as 1). TCP is a *stream of bytes*, not *messages*. You're not guaranteed to receive the whole "chunk" of whatever the other side put in a `Write` call.

Comment: And another "this isn't a fix for your current issue" comment - I've just spotted that you're calling `ConvertFromUtf32` on the *bytes* in your buffer. The only way this can be working "right" (i.e. not already causing all kinds of issues) is if the data is in fact just characters from the 7-bit ASCII range. So why are you trying to use the UTF32 decoding function?

Answer (score 0):

From the .NET [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.flush?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> The Flush method implements the Stream.Flush method; however, because NetworkStream is not buffered, it has no affect on network streams.

You can also the the released .NET source code for `NetworkStream` [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/NetworkStream.cs,caa5b7f11286fa6f,references).
`Flush` is an empty method.

Comment: I tried but still same ..old data still in network stream when i send again 2nd time command

Answer (score 0):

I see several issues on your code, like @Damien_The_Unbeliever already pointed out. For example please avoid things like this:

```
string String = "";
```

Use a more meaningful variable name, like `message`.

But I think your problem is that you get the stream several times. You get then a new stream that still contains the already handled data.

Try to get the stream once after the connection is established and use than this instance for sending and receiving.